# Dynamically change the aria-valuenow of a Bootstrap progress-bar in a VueJS component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am building a website using VueJS and Bootstrap. I chose to use "Vanilla" Bootstrap, and not a VueJS framework such as VueBootstrap or VueStrap.

I am trying to build a custom component wrapping a Boostrap progress-bar, and would like it to have a `value` data attribute that could change over time. With the following code, why isn't the component rerendering when its `value`change ? Shouldn't `v-bind` allow that ? Here is my code :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Item</h1>
    <div class="progress" style="height: 50px;">
      <div
        class="progress-bar"
        role="progressbar"
        style="width: 25%;"
        v-bind:aria-valuenow="value"
        aria-valuemin="0"
        aria-valuemax="100"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      value: 0,
      timer: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.value = 25 + Math.random() * 75;
      console.log(this.value);
    }, 2000);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.timer = null;
  }
};
</script>
```

I can see the logs in my console, but nothing moves in the progress bar.

My end goal is to animate the component so that on load, the value progressively changes from 0 to a given value.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the `aria-valuenow` does not control the visual width of the progress bar, the `style="width: 25%"` does.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      value: 0,
      timer: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.value = 25 + Math.random() * 75;
      // console.log(this.value);
    }, 2000);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.timer = null;
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Item</h1>
  <div class="progress" style="height: 50px;">
    <div
         class="progress-bar"
         role="progressbar"
         v-bind:style="{ width: value + '%'}"
         v-bind:aria-valuenow="value"
         aria-valuemin="0"
         aria-valuemax="100"
         ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```